# While using Playground - build succes, but no launch and sound

Tags: audiokit

When I open playgrounds and press Build (or run), the message "Build Success" appears, but no launch of the code.

Before I set up Xcode Project with AudioKit framework, and built oscillator project successfully with launching on Iphone simulator and produced sound.

But when open playground - only build success and no launch and no messages in console

Comment: Maybe your project is not doing anything: post what you have done if you want further help.

Comment: Sorry, issue resolved, needed to change to "automatically run". sorry for my newbuyness)

Comment: I have same problem. Which gizmo, button, parameter ... do you change to Automatically run?

Comment: As I remember - I played with play/stop buttons (also with right click menu) under the playground window